# Why do I have access to the review queue?

Tags: discussion, beta, review-queues

For some reason, the system appears to give the privilege at 15 reputation. On most sites, this is much higher. Is this because this site is in beta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reputation requirements for privileges are [lowered in Beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160292/1200429). You can see all the privileges [here](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).

Comment: To specify, it is because this site is in Private Beta, it is different in public beta (still lowered from Stack Overflow but higher than public beta)